# Which of the following is divergent? $\sum\frac1n\sin^2\frac1n$, $\sum\frac1{n^2}\sin\frac1n$, $\sum\frac1n\log n$, $\sum\frac1n\tan\frac1n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Which of the following is divergent?
>
> (a) $\displaystyle \quad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})$
>
> (b) $\displaystyle \quad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sin(\frac{1}{n})$
>
> (c) $\displaystyle \quad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log n$
>
> (d) $\displaystyle \quad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\tan (\frac{1}{n})$

My attempt:

$\sin(x)\le x$ so for option (b) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sin(\frac{1}{n})\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ which is convergent. Hence, series in (b) is convergent.

For option (a)
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$ . However, I am not sure if the inequality I have used is correct. Can someone please check this and explain how to workout for options (c) and (d).

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Asymptotic comparison with $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\zeta(2)$ or $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^3}=\zeta(3)$ rules out (a),(b),(d). And about (c) $$ \log^2(n+1)-\log^2(n)=\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\log(n)+\log(n+1)\right)$$ gives $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\log n}{n}\sim \frac{\log^2(N)}{2}\to +\infty.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n\sin^2\left(\frac1n\right)}{\frac1{n^3}}=1$$and therefore the first series converges.

You always have (unless $n$ is $1$ or $2$) $\frac{\log n}n>\frac1n$ and therefre the third series diverges.

And$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n\tan\left(\frac1n\right)}{\frac1{n^2}}=1.$$So, the fourth series converges.

Answer (score 2):

As these are series with positive terms, the simplest uses *asymptotic equivalents*:

We know that $\sin \frac1 n,\tan\frac1n\sim_\infty\frac1n$, so
$$\frac1n\,\tan\frac1 n\sim_\infty\frac 1{n^2},$$
which is a convergent $p$-series (the same argument would work for $a)$ and $b)$ as well).

As to $d)$, just observe that
$$\frac{\log n}n>\frac1n\quad\text{ if $n\ge 3$}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute values for your first inequality.

For (c) we use integral comparison :

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \sim \int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln(t)}{t}dt=+\infty$$

hence **(c) is divergent**.

---

For (d) use :

$$ \tan(\frac{1}{n})<\dfrac{1}{n} $$ and the positivity of $\tan$ above $0$.

So **(d) is convergent.**